# Extend filename with word from file -

Tags: bash, awk, printing

I can change the filename for a file to the first word in the file.

```
for fname in lrccas1
do
cp $fname $(head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1}')
done
```

But I would like to extend it inset.

```
for fname in lrccas1
do
cp $fname $(head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1 FILENAME}')
done
```

I have tried different variations of this, but none seem to work.
Is there an easy solution?

Kind regards Svend

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts/code, could you please do add samples of input and expected output in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to ask. Do you mean `cp lrccas1 lrccas1."$(awk '{ print $1; exit }' lrccas)"`? (Or, more likely, `mv` instead of `cp`?) The `for` loop over a single filename is obviously unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let understand why you did not get desired result

```
head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1 FILENAME}'
```

You are redirecting standard output of `head` command to `awk` command, that is `awk` is reading standard input and therefore `FILENAME` is set to empty string. Asking GNU `AWK` about `FILENAME` when it does consume standard input does not make much sense, as only data does through pipe and there might not such things as input file at all, e.g.

```
seq 10 | awk '{print $1*10}'
```

Secondly, let find way to get desired result, you have access to filename and successfully extracted word, therefore you might concat them that is

```
for fname in lrccas1
do
cp $fname "$(head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1}')$fname"
done
```

Thirdly, I must warn you that your command does copy (`cp`) rather than rename file (`rm`) and does not care if target name does exist or not - if it do, it will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in pure `bash` (or `sh`)

```
for fname in lrccas1
do
    read -r word rest < "$fname" && cp "$fname" "$word$fname"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do what your shell script appears to be trying to do:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=$1 FILENAME} {print > out}' lrccas1
```

but you might want to consider something like this instead:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=$1 FILENAME "_new"} {print > out}' *.txt
```

so your newly created files don't overwrite your existing ones and then to also remove the originals would be:

```
awk 'FNR==1{close(out); out=$1 FILENAME "_new"} {print > out}' *.txt &&
rm -f *.txt
```

That assumes your original files have some suffix like `.txt` or other way of identifying the original files, or you have all of your original files into some directory such as $HOME/old and can put the new files in a new directory such as $HOME/new:

```
cd "$HOME/old" &&
mkdir -p "$HOME/new" &&
awk -v newDir="$HOME/new" 'FNR==1{close(out); out=newDir "/" $1 FILENAME} {print > out}' * &&
echo rm -f *
```

remove the `echo` when done testing and happy with the result.

Answer (score 0):

try to execute this: (bash)

```
for fname in file_name
do
cp $fname "$(head -1 -q $fname|awk '{print $1}')$fname"
done
```